# Manual line break in Microsoft Word: identifying number followed by a dot

Tags: microsoft-word, linebreaks

I've the following sample of text. Is it possible to use the function find and replace in Microsoft Word in order to replace all the numbers followed by a dot with a double line break (^l^l)?

```
1. Il terremoto è un movimento di una porzione più o meno grande di superficie terrestre, costituito da oscillazioni del terreno che si succedono per un periodo di tempo. 2. All'inizio del XX secolo grazie alla rete mondiale di stazioni sismografiche si poté conoscere quale fosse la distribuzione globale dei terremoti sulla superficie terrestre. 3. La distribuzione dei terremoti è concentrata principalmente in zone che seguono i confini delle zolle. 4. L'attività sismica è principalmente associata a movimenti relativi delle zolle litosferiche. 5. La Faglia è definita come una frattura di masse rocciose accompagnata da spostamento di una delle parti (labbro) lungo il piano di frattura (piano di faglia). 6. La scala Mercalli individua 12 gradi, in base alla percezione del terremoto e all'intensità dei danni. 7. La scala Mercalli è stata aggiornata in Europa dalla European Macroseismic Scale (EMS-98).
```

Sample 2:

```
1. A seguito del terremoto la costruzione subisce nello SLV: Rotture e crolli dei componenti non strutturali ed impiantistici e significativi danni dei componenti strutturali cui si associa una perdita significativa di rigidezza nei confronti delle azioni orizzontali, la costruzione conserva invece una parte della resistenza e rigidezza per azioni verticali e un margine di sicurezza nei confronti del collasso per azioni sismiche orizzontali 2. Ai fini della mitigazione del rischio di liquefazione i pali di fondazione devono: Innestarsi ad una profondità maggiore dello strato liquefacibile 3. Ai fini sismici i terreni devono essere investigati e classificati attraverso: La determinazione della velocità media di propagazione delle onde di taglio (onde S) nei primi 30m 4. Al crescere della ripidità del versante: l'amplificazione cresce 5. All'aumentare del contenuto di fine il CRR: Aumenta 6. All'inizio del XX secolo grazie alla rete mondiale di stazioni sismografiche si poté conoscere: Quale fosse la distribuzione globale dei terremoti sulla superficie terrestre 7. Applicando un carico verticale e centrato, crescente nel tempo, ad una fondazione otteniamo una curva carico cedimento: 8. Non lineare 9. Assegnati il peso dell’unità di volume 17,76kN/m3, il contenuto d’acqua 10% e il peso specifico della sostanza solida 27KN/m3 la porosità è pari a: 0,402 10. Assegnati il peso dell'unità di volume 17,76kN/m3 contenuto d'acqua 10% e il peso specifico della sost… solida 27kN/ m3 il peso secco dell'unità di volume è: 16,15 kn/M3 11. Calcolare la tensione orizzontale geostatica totale alla profondità di 6m con riferimento ad un sottosuolo omogeneo con gamma saturo = 18kN/m3 e angolo di attrito l=30° e falda stazionaria a piano campagna: 84 12. Caquot determinò per il carico limite una formula: Binomia 13. Dal decremento logaritmico di un sistema in oscillazione libera è possibile calcolare: Rigidezza e fattore di smorzamento del sistema 14. Dopo l'applicazione di ciascun incremento di carico, il carico complessivo (σi = σi-1+ Δσi) è: Lasciato agire per un 15. intervallo di tempo sufficientemente lungo da assicurare la completa dissipazione degli eccessi di pressione neutra indotti dall'incremento di carico applicato (Δσi) 16. Durante la prova triassiale drenata si misura: La deformazione assiale e di volume 17. Esposizione E corrisponde a: Una perdita di valore sia in termini di vite umane sia di carattere economico dovuta al danneggiamento prodotto da un certo terremoto 18. Fattori 2D che influenzano l’amplificazione topografica sono: indotti dalla focalizzazione e dalla diffrazione delle onde 19. Gli effetti di amplificazione legati alla geometria del problema: interessano creste, rilevati, valli e pendii. 20. Gli effetti dell'eterogeneità di un deposito di terreno: Sono l'avvicinamento delle frequenze naturali e la concentrazione degli spostamenti in superficie 21. Gli stati limite per le fondazioni profonde da considerare secondo le NTC 2008 sono: Collasso per carico limite verticale; collasso per carico limite orizzontale; liquefazione; spostamenti o rotazioni eccessive; rottura elementi strutturali 22. Gli stati limite ultimi previsti sono: Cinque 23. Grazie alle relazioni di Eulero è possibile esprimere: Il segnale nel campo dei numeri complessi come combinazione lineare di forme d'onda esponenziali 24. I cedimenti indotti a parità di sovrastruttura dipendono: dalla tipologia della fondazione e dalle caratteristiche di deformabilità del sottosuolo 25. I cedimenti sono dovuti a: variazioni di tensioni efficaci indotte da sovraccarichi 26. I coefficienti del carico limite (Nq, Nc e Ng) sono funzioni crescenti: Dell'angolo di attrito 27. I coefficienti di indagine aumentano con: Il numero di determinazioni 28. I coefficienti Nq, Nc, Ngamma, in condizioni non drenate sono pari a: 1 – 5, 14 -0 29. I coefficienti parziali gR per i pali sono: Diversi a seconda dell'approccio considerato 30. I meccanismi di collasso possibili di una fondazione superficiale sono: Rottura generale e punzonamento 31. I metodi sismici in foro rappresentano: Una importante classe di prove in sito che consente di indagare il comportamento del terreno naturale a bassi livelli deformativi 32. I metodi sismici in foro rappresentano: Una importante classe di prove in sito che consente di indagare il 33. comportamento del terreno naturale a bassi livelli deformativi 34. I mezzi di indagine in sito diretti per la determinazione della pressione interstiziale sono: I piezometri 35. I mezzi di indagine in sito diretti per la determinazione della stratigrafia sono: Gli scavi pozzi, cunicoli e trincee e i sondaggi 36. I pali devono essere progettati per resistere a due tipi di azioni: Le forze di inerzia derivanti dalla sovrastruttura e le forze cinematiche derivanti dall'interazione palo-terreno 37. I parametri che si ottengono da una prova di taglio diretto sono: di resistenza al taglio 38. I parametri di resistenza al taglio per i terreni nc sono: Angolo di attrito 39. I parametri di resistenza al taglio per i terreni oc sono: Coesione, angolo di attrito e dilatanza 40. I parametri strettamente necessari nella caratterizzazione geotecnica dei terreni ai finidell'analisi di risposta sismica locale sono: Spessore degli strati, Densità, Velocità delle onde di taglio 41. I risultati di una prova triassiale si possono rappresentare: Nel piano di Mohr, delle tensioni principali e degli invarianti 42. I terreni in cui è possibile prelevare campioni indisturbati si definiscono: Campionabili 43. I valori caratteristici delle grandezze fisiche e meccaniche da attribuire ai terreni devono essere ottenuti mediante: Specifiche prove di laboratorio su campioni indisturbati di terreno e attraverso l'interpretazione dei risultati di prove e misure in sito 44. I Vantaggi dei sondaggi rispetto agli scavi sono: possibilità di attraversare qualsiasi terreno, anche a grande profondità e sotto falda; tempi e costi di esecuzione relativamente contenuti rispetto agli scavi - facilità di occlusione del foro 45. Il campionamento è: Un'operazione ideale che dovrebbe consentire di estrarre dal sottosuolo un volume di terreno del quale viene modificato lo stato tensionale in assoluta assenza di deformazioni 46. Il campionatore più adatto per terreni di media consistenza è: Carotiere semplice 47. Il capitolo della Circolare 2.II.2009, n. 617 (Istruzioni per l'applicazione delle NTC D.M. 14.I.2008) relativo alla progettazione geotecnica è: C6 48. Il capitolo della NTC 2008 (D.M. 14.I.2008 ) che riguarda la progettazione delle opere geotecniche è: Il sesto 49. Il Capitolo delle NTC (DM 14/01/2008) relativo alla progettazione geotecnica statica è: Il Capitolo 6 50. Il Capitolo delle NTC (DM 14/01/2008) relativo alla progettazione sismica è: Il Capitolo 7 51. Il carico limite di una fondazione superficiale in condizioni non drenate è: funzione crescente della coesione non drenata 52. Il carico limite orizzontale si calcola per: Per il palo singolo indipendentemente da quello assiale 53. Il carico limite orizzontale si valuta con la teoria di: Broms 54. Il cedimento assoluto è dato da: l'integrale (esteso allo spessore di sottosuolo coinvolto, H) degli accorciamenti infinitesimi dw 55. il cedimento differenziale è: prodotto dalle disomogeneità stratigrafiche e meccaniche del sottosuolo 56. il cedimento finale di una fondazione, posta su uno strato di spessore D, è espresso da: S∞∫ₒᵈϵ(Z,t∞)DZ 111. La fondazione può essere: superficiale; profonda 112. La frequenza delle indagini cresce con: La non uniformità del sottosuolo e importanza dell'opera 113. La frequenza naturale di una valle alluvionale superficiale: è prossima a quella monodimensionale solo al centro 114. La funzione di trasferimento è: Il rapporto tra la trasformata di Fourier del segnale in superficie e al bedrock 115. La geometria della fondazione deve essere tale da: Trasferire al terreno i carichi in maniera compatibile con la resistenza di questo ultimo e con la funzionalità del manufatto 116. La geotecnica moderna nasce nel: 1925, anno di pubblicazione della fondamentale opera di K. Terzaghi sulla “Meccanica dei terreni” 117. La liquefazione avviene: Nei terreni a grana grossa 118. La liquefazione comporta anche: La modifica del segnale sismico 119. La liquefazione inoltre comporta: Instabilità di fondazioni, argini, muri di sostegno 120. La liquefazione si verifica quando il rapporto tra sovrapressione neutra e tensione efficace litostatica è: Pari a uno 121. La magnitudo locale ML è definita come: Il logaritmo del rapporto tra l'ampiezza A e l'ampiezza A0 di riferimento 122. La mappa di pericolosità sismica dell'OPCM 3519/2006 fornisce i seguenti dati: l'accelerazione orizzontale massima su affioramento rigido con piano campagna orizzontale, riferita ad un ampio intervallo di tempi di ritorno (TR=30-2475 anni), su una griglia di passo 0.02° (circa 2 km); 123. La Microzonazione Sismica si può definire come: L'identificazione e la mappatura a scala comunale di zone 124. omogenee dal punto di vista della pericolosità sismica e anche idrogeologica locale 125. La modalità di prova consiste nel: Infissione dell'attrezzatura da piano campagna
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about singe digit you can use something like

```
([0-9]).
```

in **Find what:** field and

```
^p^p
```

in **Replace with:** field

Do not forget to mark **Use wildcards**.

[image]

If you have editor which support "full" regex the search string should be something like:

```
([0-9]{1,3}.\s)
```

(AFAIK this is **NOT** supported by Microsoft)

Comment: I added a second sample of text. In this case what should I write? The ([0-9]). expression doesn't work properly.

Comment: @FedericaGuidotti, unfortunately I am not aware of way to manage such complex text. ARAIK Microsoft Word do not support full range or regex expressions.